# Toggle class is not working

Tags: jquery, css

I have three play buttons, for a simple custom player, listed in this way:

```
<div>
  <div class="gs-player">
    <div id="gs1" onclick="play(309689093)" class="fa fa-3x fa-play"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gs-player">
    <div id="gs2" onclick="play(316017522)" class="fa fa-3x fa-play"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gs-player">
    <div id="gs3" onclick="play(315363199)" class="fa fa-3x fa-play"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I would like to do, when I click on each of them is:

1. Remove all the active class (I use `fa-pause`)
2. Toggle with the class `fa-pause` the `div` I clicked

I did in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fa-play').click(function () {
      $('.fa-pause').removeClass('fa-pause'); 
      $(this).toggleClass('fa-pause');          
    });
});
```

Basically it works fine except for the toggle function, it seems more like an addClass instead. If i click one again on the active `div`, it doesn't remove `fa-pause`.

The behavior in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wwhn9gqz/2/) is more clear.

Also, is there a way to do this without use a framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing the class then toggling it back on.  Add `.not(this)`, to avoid this.  It will ensure that the elements modified won't be the current one being clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fa-play').click(function () {
      $('.fa-pause').not(this).removeClass('fa-pause'); 
      $(this).toggleClass('fa-pause');          
    });
});

function play () {}; //remove this line, I used this just to avoid error (because we don't have your full code).
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div>
  <div class="gs-player">
    <div id="gs1" onclick="play(309689093)" class="fa fa-3x fa-play"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gs-player">
    <div id="gs2" onclick="play(316017522)" class="fa fa-3x fa-play"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gs-player">
    <div id="gs3" onclick="play(315363199)" class="fa fa-3x fa-play"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do `$('.fa-pause').removeClass('fa-pause');` by yourself, toggle is mentioned for that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fa-play').click(function () {
      $('.fa-pause').not(this).removeClass('fa-pause');
      $(this).toggleClass('fa-pause');          
    });
});
```